# Why doesn't my save system work on IOS?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I am building an IOS game in Unity. I have constructed a save system and it seems to function as expected in editor, but does not when I release a build to my device. Additionally, if there is some fatal flaw with this architecture, please let me know, as I have not seen someone build a system quite like this.

I am using (scriptable object) databases of (scriptable object) models for all of the data in my game. Each model has a serializable version that I convert between when saving / loading. The system is primarily defined by the following template class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A base class for ScriptableObject databases, providing common functionality and a singleton instance.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDatabase">The type of the database.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">The type of the ScriptableObject model the database stores.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TSerializable">The serializable version of the model.</typeparam>
public abstract class BaseDatabase<TDatabase, TModel, TSerializable>
    : ScriptableObject,
        IDatabase
    where TDatabase : BaseDatabase<TDatabase, TModel, TSerializable>
    where TModel : BaseModel<TModel>
    where TSerializable : BaseSerializableModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The list of item models in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public List<TModel> Items = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// The dictionary of item models in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, TModel> ItemDictionary = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// The inspector-set ID of the database.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    protected string id;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the singleton instance of the database.
    /// </summary>
    public static TDatabase Instance { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ID of the database.
    /// </summary>
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type of the database.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract DatabaseType Type { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the database, populating the item dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        if (Items == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Items list is null.");
            return;
        }

        if (Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Items list is empty.");
            return;
        }

        foreach (TModel item in Items)
        {
            if (ItemDictionary.ContainsKey(item.Id))
            {
                continue;
            }

            ItemDictionary.Add(item.Id, item);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a random item from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The random item.</returns>
    public virtual TModel GetRandomItem()
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Items list is empty.");
            return null;
        }

        return Instantiate(Items[Random.Range(0, Items.Count)]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an item from the database by ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The ID of the item to get.</param>
    /// <param name="suppressWarnings">Whether to suppress warnings.</param>
    /// <returns>The item.</returns>
    public virtual TModel GetItem(string id, bool suppressWarnings = false)
    {
        if (ItemDictionary.Count == 0)
        {
            if (!suppressWarnings)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Item dictionary is empty.");
            }

            return null;
        }

        if (!ItemDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            if (!suppressWarnings)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Item dictionary does not contain key: " + id);
            }

            return null;
        }

        return Instantiate(ItemDictionary[id]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes a ScriptableObject model item into a serializable version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to serialize.</param>
    /// <returns>The serialized item.</returns>
    public abstract TSerializable SerializeItem(TModel item);

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a serializable version of a model into a scriptableObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to deserialize.</param>
    /// <returns>The deserialized item.</returns>
    public abstract TModel DeserializeItem(TSerializable item);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the singleton instance of the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Thrown when there is already an instance of the database.</exception>
    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this as TDatabase;
        }
        else if (Instance != this)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("There can only be one instance of a database.");
        }
    }
}
```

The "PlayerProfile" represents the root of the save data structure. My save manager performs serialization and handles the actual file IO:

```
/// <summary>
/// Manages game save data.
/// </summary>
public static class SaveManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current player profile.
    /// </summary>
    public static PlayerProfile PlayerProfile { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the save manager.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        VerifyOrCreateSaveFile();
        TryLoadPlayerProfileFromFile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the player profile.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ResetPlayerProfile()
    {
        PlayerProfile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<PlayerProfile>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the player profile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newProfile">The new player profile.</param>
    public static void SetPlayerProfile(PlayerProfile newProfile)
    {
        PlayerProfile = newProfile;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the player profile to file.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SaveGame()
    {
        string path = GetSaveFilePath();

        SerializablePlayerProfile serializablePlayerProfile =
            PlayerProfileDatabase.Instance.SerializeItem(PlayerProfile);

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(serializablePlayerProfile, true);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    private static void VerifyOrCreateSaveFile()
    {
        string path = GetSaveFilePath();
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            Debug.Log("Save file did not exist and was created at " + path);
        }
    }

    private static void TryLoadPlayerProfileFromFile()
    {
        string path = GetSaveFilePath();
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Cannot load player profile, path does not exist.");
        }

        string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        SerializablePlayerProfile serializedPlayerProfile =
            JsonUtility.FromJson<SerializablePlayerProfile>(json);

        if (serializedPlayerProfile != null)
        {
            PlayerProfile = PlayerProfileDatabase.Instance.DeserializeItem(
                serializedPlayerProfile
            );
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerProfile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<PlayerProfile>();
        }
    }

    private static string GetSaveFilePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "playerProfile.GameSaves.json");
    }
}
```